# XML transform and linebreak characters

Tags: java, xml

ok, i have code which works on this xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<record-table>  
    <record>
        <record_id>1</record_id>
        <record_rows>
          <record_row>abcdef</record_row>
        </record_rows>
      </record>
      <record>
        <record_id>2</record_id>
        <record_rows>
          <record_row>abcdef</record_row>
          <record_row>abcdef</record_row>
        </record_rows>
      </record>
</record-table>
```

The code splits initial XML file into 2 files, and also tries to add some tags afterwards.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import javax.xml.stream.XMLInputFactory;
import javax.xml.stream.XMLOutputFactory;
import javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamConstants;
import javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamReader;
import javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamWriter;
import javax.xml.transform.Transformer;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory;
import javax.xml.transform.stax.StAXSource;
import javax.xml.transform.stax.StAXResult;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamResult;
import javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException;

import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import javax.xml.transform.OutputKeys;


public class ver2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception  {
        XMLInputFactory xif = XMLInputFactory.newInstance();
        xif.setProperty("javax.xml.stream.isCoalescing", true);
        XMLStreamReader xsr = xif.createXMLStreamReader(new FileReader("out.xml"));

        XMLOutputFactory factory = XMLOutputFactory.newInstance();

        TransformerFactory tf = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
        Transformer t = tf.newTransformer();

        xsr.nextTag(); 
        int i=0;
        while(xsr.hasNext()) {
            int event = xsr.next();
            if (event== XMLStreamConstants.START_ELEMENT){
                        if (xsr.getLocalName().equals("record")){
                        i++;
                        File file = new File(i + ".txt");

                             try {
                             XMLStreamWriter writer = factory.createXMLStreamWriter(new   FileWriter(file));

                             t.transform(new StAXSource(xsr), new StAXResult(writer)); 

                            writer.writeStartElement("addSomeTags");
                            writer.writeCharacters("\r\n");
                            writer.writeStartElement("somestuff");

                            writer.writeEndElement();
                            writer.writeEndElement();


                            writer.flush();
                            writer.close();

                         } catch (XMLStreamException e) {
                             e.printStackTrace();
                         } catch (IOException e) {
                             e.printStackTrace();
                         }

                    }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that when i open resulting files in notepad, notepad doesn't recognize linebreak characters. (probably because they are "/n", not "/n/r") At the same time if i transformed StaxSource into StreamResult (not employing XMLStreamWriter) notepad would recognize them. Can you explain why it happens, and, how to make it well-formated?

(but as you understand it IS presented properly in wordPad or other text Editors including this one)

**Also**, if this way is perverse in some way, please, let me know.

Answer (score 2):

Change code from

```
writer.writeCharacters("\r\n");
```

to

```
write.writeCharacters(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
```

This is more generic and should work better 
than `\r\n` which would only work on windows.

Comment: nono, you didn't get my problem. "\r\n" was there by accident, the question is how to make **t.transform(new StAXSource(xsr), new StAXResult(writer));** write out code with linebreaks.

Comment: (which would be recognized by notepad)

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to add these two properties to your transformer. You can omit the second one if you don't actually want it to indent; it'll just put each open-tag on a new line with no indentation.

```
    t.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");
    t.setOutputProperty("{http://xml.apache.org/xslt}indent-amount", "2");
```

Is this what you were looking for? Here's a full block of code that will format the XML in the first line and pretty-print it to the file specified in the second line. On my Windows 7 machine, Notepad opens it just fine and recognizes the linebreaks etc.

```
    Reader in = new StringReader("<a><b>Hello</b><c><d>World</d></c></a>");
    Writer out = new FileWriter("C:\\Temp\\test.xml");

    XMLInputFactory xif = XMLInputFactory.newInstance();
    xif.setProperty("javax.xml.stream.isCoalescing", true);
    XMLStreamReader xin = xif.createXMLStreamReader(in);

    TransformerFactory tf = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
    Transformer t = tf.newTransformer();

    t.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");
    t.setOutputProperty("{http://xml.apache.org/xslt}indent-amount", "2");

    t.transform(new StAXSource(xin), new StreamResult(out));
```

Comment: 1) I was trying this, but it didn't work. My files with resulting output contain indentation information, simply notepad doesn't recognize linebreaks. If I use `t.transform(new StAXSource(xsr), new StreamResult(file));` -- don't use XMLStreamWriter, indentation exists

Comment: I edited my answer to give a full block of code that works for me, at least.

Comment: Exactly, it works when you are putting your output into StreamResult, but when it is `new StaxResult(XMLStreamWriter)` it seems to ignore any output properties, or smth like that. In your example i changed it to staxresult and got 1 line output

Comment: Why is it so important to use a `StAXResult`? That's the part I'm missing here... I feel like I've answered your original question but you keep insisting on doing it in a way that clearly doesn't work for you, and I'm curious as to why.

Comment: 1) I need to read xml, write it to some place and append additional tags using XMLStreamWriter. So, i wanted to associate XMLStreamReader with XMLStreamWriter, and this is possible using StaxSource and StaXResult. So, I read and write several items using transform, then I add tags using same XMLStreamWriter's methods. Does it make any sense? (there may be no sense, as I have no idea how it all works and what am i doing)   2) I actually did it with streamResult as you suggested, and it works, so, now it's mainly curiosity issue -- what's wrong with StaxResult

Comment: Agreed... indeed, what is wrong with `StAXResult`? I see the same results you do - there's no indentation or line breaks at all when using it. Haven't found a fix.

Answer (score 0):

It may be better for you to modify the encoding in the file.

```
FileOutputStream XmlOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(...);
Writer XmlWriterUtf8 = new OutputStreamWriter(XmlOutputStream, "UTF8");
XmlWriterUtf8.write(XmlBuffer.toString());
XmlWriterUtf8.close();
```

When you work with Windows, not necessarily the right encoding to store a file is used.